# Google OAuth2.0 Shows Login Screen But No Consent Screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oauth, google-api, google-fit

I'm having an issue using Google's OAuth2.0 protocols. In particular, I'm trying to access users' step count from the Google Fit REST API. I'm working in Unity and I've surprised myself by successfully getting an access token from Google, but whenever I make a request to the REST API it returns a 403 Forbidden error. I believe this is because whenever I log in to test the functionality, I'm brought to the Google login screen and it says that it will continue to my application, but it doesn't show a consent screen asking if it can access my Google Fit data. Instead, it proceeds to a white screen. Any advice?

Comment: What scopes did you include with your OAuth authorization request?

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that you can do, is check if your account can use that API to gather that information,to do that you can use the [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) adding the "Fitness v1" scopes.

If is working there, you will have to review your application in the cloud console and follow the steps mentioned on the API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started).